# How to force the display the "Resolve Tool" dialog in TortoiseHg 2.x?

Tags: mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

(I've done this before, and I have no idea how -- it was by luck I found it then, and I cannot for the life of me duplicate the behavior. I think it was context-specific, somehow.)

[TortoiseHg 2.x](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/whatsnew.html) adds a new "Resolve Tool" *Dialog* which displays a list of files that needs merging and allows selecting a tool per file so that each can be resolved as appropriate. (I've *seen* it before.)

> TortoiseHg 2.0 introduces a resolve dialog ... It shows the users all the files that require resolution *and those files that have been resolved*, allowing merges to be verified

*How can I get this dialog to appear on a merge that otherwise "automatically" merges?*

Thanks.

---

The "*real*" issue is that I am trying to merge A->B. There was a merge from B->A where changes from A were incorrectly taken, instead of those from B. (This changeset has since been pushed.) Now it's not possible to merge B->A again because B is an ancestor of A. When I try to do a "reverse merge" (A->B) everything "automatically merges" even though there are *incorrect* semantic differences. The new "Resolve Tool" dialog should allow me to override the automatic merging, but I *can't get it to appear*.

I could get the equivalent by merging and copying/fixing the merged files by hand. I am looking for a way to do this nicely inside TortoiseHg itself where I can select "mine", "theirs", etc. Or perhaps a backout would be more appropriate? I tried that and just ran into more issues, as I still couldn't merge B->A again, which might be [another] PEBKAC...

Additionally, I have set the settings "Three-way Merge Tool = internal:dump" and "Auto-resolve merges = false" to no avail...

---

My "solution", which feels so hackish and unorthodox to Hg, was to force a branch and then "Visual Diff..." and merge over the changes I wanted (with KDiff3). In *this* context -- but *not* after an automatic merge, which seemed to leave orphaned merge files -- the changes from the merge tool were correctly applied to the WC. It still, however, fails to address my question: how/when is the "Resolve Tool" Dialog shown? It seems too handy to not be readily available.

Comment: What if you right click on the merged files after you've merged and before you've commited the merge results. There is a merge option iirc

Comment: @zerkms I don't have such an option for the merged files :( Closest I have a "Visual diff...", but when I open that (KDiff3) and do a merge the output file itself seems abandoned somewhere in my temp directory.

Comment: Yep, surprisingly the file merged from Kdiff3 from `visual diff` is saved somewhere in tmp. Looks like a good candidate to fill a bug report